# express in words without using the symbol N

Tags: quantifiers

Express

$$\forall\ n\in\mathbb N\ \exists\ m \in\mathbb N: \ n^4 = m^2$$

in words without using the symbol $\mathbb N$.

Answer (score 4):

In words, and clearer, every perfect fourth power is a perfect square.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid usage of the term "perfect power" (in case you didn't know it), you can say

> Every fourth power of a natural number is also the square of a natural number.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $n\in \mathbb{N}$, this can be spoken as:

"For all natural numbers there exists a natural number such that the fourth power of the first is the square of the second."
i.e. "For all natural numbers every fourth power is a perfect square."

Answer (score 0):

For every n belongs to natural numbers there exists a m belongs natural numbers such that fourth power of n is equal to square of m.

Comment: Though correct, this is merely a translation of the notation into incomplete english.

Comment: I was assuming that he also don't know the meaning of the symbols @AlexR

Comment: Agreed with AlexR. Especially when there are lots of quantifiers, the hard part is translating the sentence into natural English, **not** just mechanically replacing $\forall $ with "for all" and $\exists$ with "there exists".

Comment: @user291957 The question sounds more like an assignment to me, i.e. the OP is specifically _asked_ to translate the expression. This doesn't imply the OP wasn't able to understand the quantifiers.